# Fluent NHibernate - Mapping List<decimal> to ordered child table

Tags: c#, .net, orm, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm refactoring a fluent nHibernate mapping, and I can't seem to figure this one out.  I want to remap a property with type `List<decimal>` to a child table, but using a single `HasMany` if possible.

Right now we have: `Map(x => x.DecimalList);`
Which gives us a nice type of `varbinary(8000)`

In my attempts to move this to an ordered child table I've tried:

```
HasMany(x => x.DecimalList)
.Table("ParentTable_DecimalList")
.KeyColumn("Id")
.Element("Amount")
.KeyColumn("ParentId")
.Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

And this gives me the relationship, with two columns: `ParentId` and `Amount`. The only problem is that I also want to put an Order or Primary Key/ID column on the child table to ensure that we preserve the list's ordering no matter what.

**Is there a way to add a strong int Primary Key column and / or an Order column without busting this out to a more complex child object/map?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map it as a list

```
HasMany(x => x.DecimalList)
...
.AsList(x => x.WithColumn("ListPosition")
```

By default, it is mapped as a bag, which doesn't preserve the order.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that having a list like this without a child object container can be a bit of a code smell.  Unless of course the list is truly a list of value objects that have no identity.  I eventually refactored to a child object container layout, but it's still nice to know how to do it this way.  Thanks again!

Comment: Adding AsList(x => x.WithColumn("ListPosition") is creating null object in the list . Any help

Comment: Ask a new question. Have complete but minimal code to reproduce the issue.